# Load pdf in html by embeding or using iframe in app

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

Building an app and I need to show a pdf on a screen within the app. I am open to either embedding it or using an iframe, but no matter what I do, I can't see the right side of the document. I can see it lengh-wise but no resizing methods are working to see the entire width. Two of my 100 approaches are below. Any help would be great. Designing for iPhone 6 primarily.

```
<embed src="filename.pdf" width="375" height="625">

<iframe id="menupdf" src="filename.pdf#zoom=100" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe
```

Comment: I don't see your approaches.

Comment: Why do you set fixed width?

Comment: I've tried setting them and not setting them. nothing seems to works